# Portable "install" command

Tags: shell, installation, posix

My Makefile was failed on Solaris 11 because `install` command in not in the POSIX and so have different usage syntax (I use GNU variant).

I use it to copy files into desired places and to set permission.

What is portable alternative to `install` command?

Comment: `cp`, `chmod` and `chown`?

Answer (score 1):

cmake is the portable version of make so it will not depend on unportable commands.

https://cmake.org/

It will be available as a solaris package.

Comment: `cmake` is available in official Solaris repository: http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/en/search.shtml?token=cmake and in community https://www.opencsw.org/package/cmake/ But it have its own issues ((